# How can I read out data from a SQLite database and list them?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I like to ask, how I can read data from my databast "test_database.db" and list them on my screen?

Database: test_database.db

Table: tbl_homework

```
In table homework are those entries:
ID             HW
1              Mathematics
2              Physics
3              Sports
```

So i know how I can send ONE entry to a toast or alert. (With cursor)
I read that tutorial here but I can't build that example for my app.
http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/

What do I have?
Java: CustomDatabaseHelper.java, homework.java, main.java

Layout: homework.xml, main.xml

homework.java is a normal activity I tried to change it to ListActivity. But then it crashes.

Here the code: (It works fine)

```
public class homework extends Activity {
SQLiteDatabase db;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homework);

    //Create Database
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("test_database.db", 
            SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

    db.setVersion(1);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);

    //Create table tbl_homework
    final String CREATE_TABLE_HW =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_homework ("
            + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "hw TEXT);";

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_HW);

    press_cmd_back();
    press_cmd_test_data();

}

//What will happen if cmd_back gets pressed
private void press_cmd_back(){
    Button cmd_back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmd_back);
    cmd_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Intent_main = new Intent(homework.this, Noten_HausaufgabenActivity.class);
            startActivity(Intent_main);
        }
    });
}



//What will happen if cmd_test_data gets pressed
    private void press_cmd_test_data(){
        Button cmd_test_data = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmd_test_data);
        cmd_test_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            open_database_rw();
            final String INSERT_DATA_1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_homework ('hw') VALUES ('Mathematics')";
            final String INSERT_DATA_2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_homework ('hw') VALUES ('Physics')";
            final String INSERT_DATA_3 = "INSERT INTO tbl_homework ('hw') VALUES ('Sports')";


            db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA_1);
            db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA_2);
            db.execSQL(INSERT_DATA_3);

        }
    });

}

//Open Database RW
private void open_database_rw() {
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/test.marco.notenha/databases/test_database.db", 
            null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

}
```

Comment: i'm confused... so you want to bind the data to a listview on the main activity's screen?

Comment: Sorry for my explanation I am German and should lern some more English. I like to bind the data to a listview on the same activity's screen. (homework)

Comment: Retagged the question to help you to get help.

Comment: @EvertonAgner I can't edit my question at the moment. 2 posts befor I wrote what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really haven't given us a lot of information... I'm not sure why your code is crashing, what the file `R.layout.homework` contains, etc.

You need two things to bind data to a ListView in your ListActivity. 1) You need a Cursor to read the columns of interest, and 2) you need an Adapter to bind the database rows to a ListView. Therefore, you need to implement a method that queries the database and returns a Cursor over the database, and you also need to create a `SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter` (or some other subclass of `BaseAdapter` if you wish), bind the adapter to the columns of interest, and end your `onCreate()` method with something like `setListAdapter(mAdapter)`. You will also have to be careful that you don't accidentally open multiple instances of a `Cursor` or `SQLiteDatabase` without closing them, or else the system will throw an exception.

Your best bet is to check out the [**notepad tutorial**](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) on the Android Developers site. Really try to understand how everything works and you'll learn a lot. It's a great tutorial and it's very similar to what you need to get done (that is, it queries a database and binds "todo notes" to a list on the main screen). You'll also learn how to manage the `Activity` life-cycle and how to create a `SQLiteDatabase` correctly from scratch.

Hope that made sense. If it didn't, read through the notepad tutorial and then come back and read my answer and hopefully it'll make a lot more sense. I was in the same exact position as you a few months ago... it gets easier but you really have to sit down and try to understand how this stuff works first, and the notepad tutorial is a great place to start!

Good luck!

Comment: Ok tomorrow I will try to understand that tutorial again ;)
Thank you!

Comment: let me know if you have any questions later on :)